# theme_username($object) in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming

In my author_pane template, I get my user´s names trimmed as it was back then in Drupal 6.
So I went to the [api page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_username/7) (as I did in my D6 installation) and I see that the code that used to work in Drupal 6 isn´t there anymore in Drupal 7.

This was the code I´m looking for:

```
function theme_username($object) {

  if ($object->uid && $object->name) {
    // Shorten the name when it is too long or it will break many tables.
    if (drupal_strlen($object->name) > 20) {
      $name = drupal_substr($object->name, 0, 15) . '...';
    }
    else {
      $name = $object->name;
    }
```

How may I ensure in D7 that my username´s names aren´t being trimmered at 20 character´s length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code has been moved in [template_preprocess_username()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_username/7), which is called before the theme function.

```
// Set the name to a formatted name that is safe for printing and
// that won't break tables by being too long. Keep an unshortened,
// unsanitized version, in case other preprocess functions want to implement
// their own shortening logic or add markup. If they do so, they must ensure
// that $variables['name'] is safe for printing.
$name = $variables['name_raw'] = format_username($account);
if (drupal_strlen($name) > 20) {
  $name = drupal_substr($name, 0, 15) . '...';
}
```

If you need to use the full-length name, you should use `$variables['name_raw']` in your implementation of `theme_username()`, remembering that the value has not been passed to any sanitization function.

Comment: I´m using: print $account_name;, should I use $variables['name_raw'] instead? I´s ok to use name_raw in my case, as the users don´t have any "change username´s" permission, and the admin is the only one that sets thm.

Comment: In a template file, it's $name_raw; in the theme function, and in the pre/process functions it's $variables['name_raw'].